# Starting up Worklight Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am trying to run a simple HelloWorld app on my MacBook using Eclipse Luna and I am getting this message:

> The current server configuration is set to "localhost". Therefore the
>   Worklight build uses the primary IP address of this computer
>   (???.???.?.???) instead. It is recommended to set the server
>   configuration to use the fully qualified hostname or IP address of
>   this computer. To configure the setting, in the "Servers" view
>   double-click the Worklight Development Server entry and edit the "Host
>   name" field.

Clicking the Worklight Development Server opens a sub menu with different files. I believe that I need to replace localhost by my IP address. Which file and which entry need to be modified?

Answer (score 1):

It is only a recommendation and typically in most cases for local development there is no need to change this value.

If you still prefer to change it, it is where the message says so.
Open the Servers view and double-click on the "Worklight Development Server" entry (no need to expend it):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Idan. I am still not able to start the Worklight Development Server. It does not work with localhost and also when I change it to my IP address I still get the following message:

**[2014-08-17 13:17:35] FWLPL0010W: The current server configuration is set to "localhost". Therefore the Worklight build uses the primary IP address of this 
computer (192.168.1.108) instead. It is recommended to set the server configuration to use the fully qualified hostname or IP address 

I have checked port 10080. It has not been assigned to other services.
Your help is appreciated.
Sinan

Comment: [ERROR   ] TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class javax/xml/transform/sax/SAXSource with exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: I have tried setting the host name to localhost or the ip address of my machine with no luck. I cannot start the Worklight Development Server. I get the so many errors starting with TRAS0033E... as mentioned in the previous comment.Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Provide more details: what is the OS? Which Eclipse flavor did you install? What is your Java version?

Comment: Dear Idan, I have tried running Worklight Development Server on the following: Windows 8, Eclipse: Kepler Service Release 1, Build id: 20130919-0819
Java: jdk1.8.0_11. Thanks for your help

Also on MacBook OS X, Version 10.9.4
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Juno Service Release
Java SE 8 (MacOS).

Comment: Java 8 is not supported in Worklight for Windows 8. Downgrade  or install Java 6 or 7. Make sure that in Eclipse, you set it to use this Java 6 or 7.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend. I switched to Java 7 and all the errors disappeared but still the server does not start. I increased the time to 360 seconds with no luck. Any hint please?

Comment: I have no more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the same problem. I had to change the Host Name to the name of my PC and it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I disagree, because this answer will in fact, make that warning go away and solve the problem.

Comment: And I stand by my comment; the OP said: " I believe that I need to replace localhost by my IP address. Which file and which entry need to be modified?"  Your answer provided no useful guidance for this question.

Comment: "Clicking the Worklight Development Server opens a sub menu with different files. I believe that I need to replace localhost by my IP address. Which file and which entry need to be modified?" The field is called "HostName" and you put your pc name in it. He is already in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

@Simon, Can you do a DNS flush on your mac once and give it a try. Sometimes DNS flush causes some sort of unwanted issues which doesnt resolve the ip address and acts funny
refer :- [link](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202516)